# How should I prune a top heavy Jade plant?

Tags: houseplants, pruning, succulents, jade

I have had a Jade plant over 15 years. It thrives most of the time, however this morning I found it toppled over from being so full at the top of the plant.  I have never pruned it and am very afraid of doing it wrong and damaging the plant.

How should I go about pruning it so that it's not so top-heavy?

Comment: Please update your question with some photographs of the plant and its container. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well the obvious solution would be to pot it in a bigger heaver pot...

But I believe you can prune jade and have the branches root.  Even the leaves will root.  You just need to let the wound dry out for a few days first before sticking it in water or soil.